# how to resize container view embedding uitableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I'm trying to fit scrollview's height to its total height of subviews. I'm done to fit scrollview's height but UITableView embedded in container view which is subview of scrollview is not scaled to fit scroll view. 
to the easy,

```
VC
--scroll view
----lots of container view
----container view -> UITableView
```

[storyboard of scroll view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C35Vq.png)

[below blank is what I want to fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T6pN.png)

what I want to do is stretching tableView.

here is my source code of VC.

```
import UIKit

class NormalCustomerMainViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NormalCustomerScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var AdPageView: UIView!


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NormalCustomerMain", bundle: nil)
    print(tableView.frame)
    let TableView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableView") as! NormalCustomerConstructionExampleTableViewController
    print("rectSize")

    let tableSize = TableView.tableView.rect(forSection: 0)
    print(tableView.frame)

    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableSize.size.height)
    //tableView.frame = TableView.tableView.rect(forSection: 0)
    //tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    print(tableView.frame)








    var totalHeight:CGFloat = CGFloat(0);
    var width:CGFloat = CGFloat(0)
    for uiView in self.scrollView.subviews {
        totalHeight = totalHeight + uiView.frame.height
        width = uiView.frame.width

    }
    width = self.scrollView.frame.width
    print(width)
    print(totalHeight)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: totalHeight)

        //self.tableView.frame = self.tableView.frame.union(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 1110))
    }

}
```

Comment: is it inside the container view ?

Comment: TableViewController is inside of container view.

Comment: then you need to change container view's frame instead of tableView's frame.

Comment: Because ContainerView displayed its content as per own size .

Comment: but, how to do that? I searched whole day for this problem. as you see, tableView.frame = (CGRect bla bla~~~) wasn't updated containerView's size.

Comment: change container size in storyboard **OR** connect iboutlet of that containerView and change  frame through programming .

Comment: tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableSize.size.height)


is it what you said?

Comment: if change tableview frame it will be not changed frame of containerView.

Comment: hmmm... tableview is iboutlet of container view. am I confusing now...?

Comment: you need to change frame where you contained **lots of container view**.

Comment: VC --scroll view ----lots of container view **(change here frame of container View)** ------ container view **(Not here)** -> UITableView

Comment: scrollview is containing lots of container view. in DispatchQueue.main.async, I changed size of scrollView. should I use scrollView.frame = CGRect ~~~~ rather than scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(~~~) ?

Comment: it will be not work.... if you do changes for  that containerview so it will be reflect the frame .

Comment: ok check and let me know any issue faced .